# Facebook api for invite friends

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a php based website www.darooadda.com. I want to know if there is any facebook API to invite friends from facebook account. If a user logins the webite using facebook account, he should be able to invite his facebook friends from the website.

Can anyone help me with the correct api documentation or sample php code for the same?

Comment: this doc may help you http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

this sample code can use facebook API 3.0.1, request friends and post back to your site if request sent

```
$<?php
// Requires Facebook PHP SDK 3.0.1: https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/
require ('includes/facebook.php');
define('FACEBOOK_APP_ID',"your facebook ID");
define('FACEBOOK_SECRET',"your facebook secret password");

$user = null;

// Create our Application instance (replace this with your appId and secret).
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
'appId' => FACEBOOK_APP_ID,
'secret' => FACEBOOK_SECRET,
'cookie' => true
));

$user = $facebook->getUser();
$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl();

if ( empty($user) ) {
echo("<script> top.location.href='" . $loginUrl . "'</script>");
exit();
}
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Send An Application Request Using The Facebook Graph API</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
 <div id="fb-root"></div>


<a href="#">Send Application Request</a>

<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId: '<?php echo $facebook->getAppID() ?>',
      status: true,
      cookie: true,
      oauth: true
    });
  };

  $('a').click(sendRequest);
  function sendRequest() {
    FB.ui({
      method: 'apprequests',
      message: 'Check out this application!',
      title: 'Send your friends an application request',
    },
    function (response) {
      if (response.request && response.to) {
        var request_ids = [];
        for(i=0; i<response.to.length; i++) {
          var temp = response.request + '_' + response.to[i];
          request_ids.push(temp);
        }
        var requests = request_ids.join(',');
        $.post('handle_requests.php',{uid: '<?php echo $user; ?>', request_ids: requests},function(resp) {
          // callback after storing the requests
        });
      } else {
        alert('canceled');
      }
    });
    return false;
  }

  // Load the SDK Asynchronously
  (function(d){
    var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
    js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
    d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
  }(document));
</script> 
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Does it only work for games? Or any apps? According to this, it only works for games: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/services/gamerequests

Answer (score 2):

**invite facebook friend from your website,use this small lines of code and send invitation to all facebook friends to visit your website.i also used this script its working nicely. 
your domain must be *ssl certified* because facebook didn't allowing unsecured domains.**

```
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>

<script>
FB.init({
appId:'APP_ID',
cookie:true,
status:true,
xfbml:true
});

function FacebookInviteFriends()
{
FB.ui({
method: 'apprequests',
message: 'Your Message diaolog'
});
}
</script>


//HTML Code
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<a href='#' onclick="FacebookInviteFriends();"> 
Facebook Invite Friends Link
</a>
```

add this below code to your website main page..

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
if (top.location!= self.location)
{
top.location = self.location
}
</script>
```

for more detail you can check:- http://www.9lessons.info/2012/07/facebook-invite-friends-api.html